# Adding a nullable column concurrently with an update or insert

Tags: sql-server, alter-table, concurrency, ddl

In SQL Server, when adding a column that allows nulls to a live SQL Server database with millions of rows, what happens if an insert or update is occurring at the same time as the DDL update?

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn varchar(255) NULL;
```

Answer (score 5):

Referencing the documentation for [ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) (highlighting mine),

> The changes specified in ALTER TABLE are implemented immediately. If
>   the changes require modifications of the rows in the table, ALTER
>   TABLE updates the rows. **ALTER TABLE acquires a schema modify (SCH-M)
>   lock on the table to make sure that no other connections reference
>   even the metadata for the table during the change, except online index
>   operations that require a very short SCH-M lock at the end.** In an
>   ALTER TABLE…SWITCH operation, the lock is acquired on both the source
>   and target tables. The modifications made to the table are logged and
>   fully recoverable. Changes that affect all the rows in very large
>   tables, such as dropping a column or, on some editions of SQL Server,
>   adding a NOT NULL column with a default value, can take a long time to
>   complete and generate many log records. These ALTER TABLE statements
>   should be executed with the same care as any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that affects many rows.

Also, Paul Randal has some good information about what happens when you add columns (and how long the operation might take) in [Misconceptions around adding columns to a table](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-adding-columns-to-a-table/).  To summarize some main points:

- New column is nullable, with a NULL default. The table’s metadata
  records the fact that the new column exists but may not be in the
  record. This is why the null bitmap also has a count of the number of
  columns in that particular record. SQL Server can work out whether a
  column is present in the record or not. So – this is NOT a
  size-of-data operation – the existing table records are not updated
  when the new column is added. The records will be updated only when
  they are updated for some other operation.
- New column is nullable, with a non-NULL default. It depends which
  version of SQL Server you’re using:

  - Before SQL Server 2012: This IS a size-of-data operation. The
    non-NULL default forces all existing records to be updated when the
    column is added, and so the null bitmap will be updated too.
  - SQL Server 2012 onward: same behavior as for a NULL default nullable
    column (i.e. metadata only operation)
- New column is not-nullable (obviously with a non-NULL default). This
  IS a size-of-data operation.

Comment: 2012+ Enterprise edition can add columns as metadata-only in all cases (unless you choose a non-runtime constant like NEW_ID()). Standard is stuck with size-of-data for non-null and anything with a default (regardless of nullability).

Answer (score -2):

the entire column will be null for all the records in the table

---

begin tran

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn varchar(255) NULL;

select MyColumn,* from MyTable

rollback

---

run this command and check what happens!!!

the code inside rollback update temporily so u can check ,, by modifying thecode also

Comment: *what happens if an insert or update is occurring at the same time as the DDL update?* – how does your suggestion answer that question?